# How to use key of a Json object as row entity in Spark Dataframe (in Scala)?

Tags: json, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am stuck with using key of a JSON object for creating a dataframe.
My sample data is like that:

```
{"key1": "value1", 
 "key2": { "nested1": "value2", 
           "nested2": {"deeplyNested": "value3"}
         }
}
```

I am trying to have that DataFrame in Scala-Spark:

```
key1   | PARAMETER  | deeplyNested
---------------------------------
value1 |  nested2   | value3
```

The hard part for me is creating a new column named `PARAMETER` and using key value of the JSON object as an entity of that column.

I tried to do something like that:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val jsonString = """{"key1": "value1", "key2": {"nested1": "value2", "nested2": {"deeplyNested": "value3"}}}"""
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonString).toDS)

val keys = df.select($"key2.*").columns.collect.toList
```

However, my mind got stuck and I couldn't find a way to achieve. I see something about json4s library stuff but I also couldn't understand the usage of that JSON parser in order to have a DataFrame.

How can I do that in Scala/Spark?

Comment: Where did `key2` and `value2` go in your example dataframe? Why change new column of `PARAMETER` if that doesn't match your JSON?

Comment: @OneCricketeer key2 and value2 wont be used in my example, they are just for representation. And I couldnt understand ur second question

Comment: I cannot tell what you are trying to show. You would define key1 has as StringType and key2 as a StructType with its own nested StructTypes... You should not try to make Spark infer a schema for you when you already have the data available